# how do I rename the Partition

Tags: osx-lion

I am running Windows 7 and Lion on my iMac. In Disk Utility, one partition shows up as "Unlimited" while the other shows up as "OS X".

How do I rename the partition that is named "unlimited" to "Windows 7"?

When I select options at start up, both partitions are named correctly.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments it appears GPT partitions do have names so I what I wrote below is wrong for them. The GPT partitions created by OSX appear a bit non-standard so it may not be possible to easily name them with something that is visible in Windows.

You don't since partitions don't have names. The file system volume(s) they are formatted as do however have labels/names.

Comment: You are being a smartass while not even answering the question.

Comment: Partitions *do* have names on GPT systems, including iMacs.